# Firebase database query after sometime get result

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I get all time return false but i have data. How can i get return true result. Anybody please help me to solve this question.

```
public boolean checkVechicalNumberONCheckIN(final String Vehicle_no,final Context context){

    car_return2 = false;

    sharedPreference = new SharedPreference();

    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    Query query = reference.child("raw_check_in").orderByChild("vechical_number").equalTo(Vehicle_no);
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
               car_return2 = true;    
           }


        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

   return car_return2; //here i get all time false

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return dataSnapshot value as a result of a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847694/how-to-return-datasnapshot-value-as-a-result-of-a-method)

Answer (score 2):

The firebase queries are asynchronous so you will not get the result immediately, instead you need to call some method from `onDataChange` which will contain the code that you want to execute, once you get the result

```
public void checkVechicalNumberONCheckIN(final String Vehicle_no,final Context context){

    sharedPreference = new SharedPreference();

    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    Query query = reference.child("raw_check_in").orderByChild("vechical_number").equalTo(Vehicle_no);
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {    
               executeSomeMethodOnResult(dataSnapshot.exists());

        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}

void executeSomeMethodOnResult(boolean flag){
    if(flag){// mean true}else{// flag is false}
}
```

or if this is a helper class then the optimal option is to create callback mechanism